# why is my gaussian (rbf) kernel not returning a positive definite matrix

Tags: kernel, covariance, gaussian

I cannot understand why my code for the RBF kernel does not produce a positive definite kernel. However the exponential kernel does.

```
v=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)

gau.cov = function(x, l, ss){
  d = as.matrix(x)/l
  K = exp(-0.5*d^2)
  diag(K) = diag(K) + 1e-8
  ss*K
}

eigen(gau.cov(v,2,2))

exp.cov <- function(distmatrix,l,ss){ss*exp(-as.matrix(distmatrix)/l)}

eigen(exp.cov(v,2,2))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to the correct function for the RBF please.